# django-registration custom fields on form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration

I have successfully managed to extend basic django-registration form, with custom fields on the form and it works fine.What is bugging me now is, the way it works.I have defined new Backend with register method that extends DefaultBackend

```
class MyBackend(DefaultBackend):
   def register(self, request, **kwargs):
```

created UserProfile model that holds User object as a Foreign Key

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    custom_filed = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

and defined form

```
class UserRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    custom_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict))

    model = UserProfile
```

that was supplied in urls

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$',  register, {'backend': 'app.regbackend.MyBackend','form_class':UserRegistrationForm},name='registration_register')
```

and it works fine, custom_field get saved the way I defined it in register method.What bothers me is that register form(template) only shows fields defined in `RegistrationForm`(username,email,password)model, and I have to add my `custom_field` manualy into the form class.I don't understand why is that, because model attribute points to `UserProfile`, and if I  remove `custom_field` from form class it won't be shown.Why is that?

Comment: Because your calling the RegistrationForm which only defined username, email, and password. To be able to show your custom_field together with username, email, and password, you must call the UserRegistrationForm

Comment: Hmm...did you miss to see that I call UserRegistrationForm, 'form_class':UserRegistrationForm in url string?

Comment: you forgot to put class Meta:

Comment: There is class Meta: model = UserProfile in my form class, I just forgot to copy that part...

Comment: I think I figured out what is a problem, RegistrationForm actually is not a model form...

Comment: Nice, you can fix it now :)